# "Be ready to embrace your skin color"- is this an imperative sentence?

Tags: grammar, verbs, syntactic-analysis, linguistics, imperatives

*"Be ready to embrace your skin color"* is a slogan from local beauty ads in my country and I wonder if this clause is an imperative or not? If so, does "be ready" function as a verb? And what about "to embrace" then? I'm so confused about it.

Answer (score 1):

"Be ready" is used as an instruction and "embrace" will act as verb and therefore it can be said imperative sentence.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

"Be" is the imperative verb in the sentence. You can see this if you rephrase it in the indicative:

> You are ready to embrace your skin color.

In the above sentence, "are" is the main verb of the sentence. If you restate it as an imperative, the main verb is "be," which is the imperative form of the verb "to be."